# How to get Lucene.net 3.0.3.0 to work with Azure?

Tags: azure, lucene, full-text-search, lucene.net

Alright, I've been trying to get this working for 2 days: I want to full text search on an Azure worker role. I think Lucene.NET is good for this. I've used this example: [Use AzureDirectory with Lucene.NET 3.0.3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971565/use-azuredirectory-with-lucene-net-3-0-3-0).

I'm using the code below:

```
CloudStorageAccount cloudAccount = CloudStorageAccount.FromConfigurationSetting("CloudStorageSetting");
var cacheDirectory = new RAMDirectory();
AzureDirectory azureDirectory = new AzureDirectory(cloudAccount, "MyCloudIndex", cacheDirectory);
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30);
IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(azureDirectory, analyzer, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
```

With Lucene.Net 3.0.3.0 and Lucene.Net.Store.Azure 1.0.5.1, on Azure SDK 1.8. I also tried the older Lucene.NET (2.9.xxx) but that didn't work either. I updated Windows.Azure.Storage: still doesn't work.

The problem is: Visual Studio gives me an error that the `azureDirectory` that is inserted into `IndexWriter` needs to be of type `Directory` instead of `AzureDirectory`. When I change its type to `Directory` however, it says that `AzureDirectory` is not a subtype of `Directory`.

How come ALL the examples on the internet are wrong and don't work when I literally copy paste them?

Update: the issue is fixed, I wrote a blog post about it: http://leoncullens.nl/post/2012/11/18/Full-Text-Search-on-Azure-with-LuceneNET.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have 'forked' this [project](https://azuredirectory.codeplex.com/), updated the Lucene reference to 3.0.3, and updated the Azure Storage client to 2.0 (the version that ships with v1.8 SDK), and placed the code here:

https://github.com/richorama/AzureDirectory

It should be relatively straight forward to copy the sample code in the 'TestApp' to figure out how to use this version of Lucene.NET.

*disclaimer, I am not a Lucene expert, and I haven't tested this properly - use at your own risk!

Comment: Thanks Richard! I will look into this in 2 days or so, I will let you know if it works :)

Comment: Ok, after many long struggles it appears that I have it working! :-) I had to experiment a lot, but I think it will do fine if I tweak it some more. Many thanks for the help!

Comment: Cool, a blog post would be really helpful for others to follow how to do it!

Comment: Here's the blog post http://leoncullens.nl/post/2012/11/18/Full-Text-Search-on-Azure-with-LuceneNET.aspx. I hope there aren't too many errors in it :)

Comment: I haven't tried this, but the original AzureDirectory implementation simply was not production ready.  I am not sure if simply replacing the StorageClient is enough.   If you try to compile Lucene 3.0.3 (source code) with the library is requires some major changes to the AzureDirectory code. I have everything working Azure IaaS and had no problems.

Comment: What are the shortcomings in the implementation? I haven't spent a lot of time looking at the code, I just fixed the broken references.

Answer (score 0):

Its not going work...Here is my answer on why its not and what you can do:
[How to implement Lucene .Net search on Azure webrole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222479/how-to-implement-lucene-net-search-on-azure-webrole/13223048#13223048)

Here is another answer that might help, but I don't agree with the approach:
https://azuredirectory.codeplex.com/discussions/402913

Edit: I should clarify that when I say "work" I mean work in a production environment.

Comment: I think I already came across your post. That sounds like an awful amount of work. Can't this be done easier by using a different FTS engine, or another library (like SimpleLucene)?

Comment: SimpleLucene is not an implementation of the Directory class from Lucene..AzureDirectory is an abstraction that works on the blob storage in Azure.  SimpleLucene is just takes the Lucene code and tries to make it "easier to use".  Lucene 3.0.3 just came out..it woks really well on the native file system (Directory object) on a VM.  How familiar are you with Azure IaaS?  To create an Azure VM is a fairly simple.  To your comment, you could buy it Lucene-as-a-Service: http://www.lucidworks.com/products/lucidworks-search/lucidworks-search-windows-azure

Comment: I have zero experience with IaaS so I'd rather not manage Windows Server and that kind of things myself, I prefer focusing purely on the software that I build. I'm afraid hosted Lucene.NET isn't an option either, I would at least need the Medium plan which costs me $500/month.

Comment: Well then you don't want to use Lucene 3.0.3 with the AzureDirectory...it may work in samples/examples.  If you take the source code of Lucene 3.0.3 and try to compile against the source code of AzureDirectory..it blows up everywhere.  That scared me off big time...it sounds like you "want to focus" on software, so using an older version of Lucene might be the best option for you (that second link I posted above may work).

Answer (score 0):

A couple of months ago this setup worked for me for LUCENE version 2.9 and an older Azure SDK. The main difference between working and non-working was to NOT using RAMDirectory since eventually it ran out of RAM. After NOT using RAMDirectory, I was successful in indexing 25 GB of data.

```
_azureDirectory  = new AzureDirectory
    ( storageAccount 
    , catalogName
    //, new RAMDirectory());

_version = Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29;

_analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(_version);


IndexWriter
writer = new IndexWriter(
                  _azureDirectory, 
                  _analyzer,
                  newIndex, // new index or update
                  IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);

writer.SetUseCompoundFile(false);
writer.SetRAMBufferSizeMB(800);
writer.SetMergeFactor(10);
```

Comment: Its is the parameter called 'create'.   
true - to create the index or overwrite the existing one; 
false - to append to the existing index